# How to organize github repository that is used by several products with different release cycles

Tags: git, github

We have a github repository that is used by several products (this is a C++ lib that is built and linked to). These products have different release schedule, so they have code freezes at different time. What is the recommended approach to handle this? Presently we have a branch for each product and them sync from master time to time.

There are four products.

Comment: Are these four products all derived from a single `master` branch, or did you mean that each product has its own `master`?

Comment: These for products are some applications that link against the library that lives in this repository. There are no product specific modifications in the library. The products want to use the same code, but cannot do that because of the different release cycles. They also do daily build of the library each for themselves.

Comment: Based on your answer, create a separate repositor for each product and another to the library. Add library as git submodule or even a separate git and pull from library repo. A modem like Android orlike my sugestion number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are 4 separated products and share main code (master), I would do one of the two below:

1. Use diferent branches named after product. Each developer shall create their own branch for working and push to product branch as needed (this need to be more elaborate but you got the idea). This approach seams to be what you are doing so far.
2. Use 5 different repositories, one master with dev code (master you mentioned), other 4, one for each product with branches, release tags, etc.

The 2nd method is more clear and easy to understand (product repos are fork of master at the begin but than they derived as the product goes).

Elaborate more if you want to discuss options.